# Unexplained long stop the world pauses during concurrent marking step in G1 Collector

Tags: java, garbage-collection, java-8, g1gc

We are experiencing unexplained/unknown long pauses (8 seconds) during concurrent marking step of G1 collector.

Extract from GC-log showing problem.

```
2014-08-07T13:42:30.552-0400: 92183.303: [GC concurrent-root-region-scan-start]
2014-08-07T13:42:30.555-0400: 92183.305: [GC concurrent-root-region-scan-end, 0.0025230 secs]
**2014-08-07T13:42:30.555-0400: 92183.305: [GC concurrent-mark-start]**
**2014-08-07T13:42:39.598-0400: 92192.348: Application time: 9.0448670 seconds**
2014-08-07T13:42:39.601-0400: 92192.351: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0029740 seconds
2014-08-07T13:42:39.603-0400: 92192.353: [GC pause (G1 Evacuation Pause) (young) 92192.354: [G1Ergonomics (CSet Construction) start choosing CSet, _pending_cards: 7980, predicted base time: 28.19 ms, remaining time: 71.81 ms, target pause time: 100.00 ms
```

`2014-08-07T13:42:30.555-0400: 92183.305` is when the concurrent mark starts, approximately after 2 seconds of this step the application starts to pause until the next GC pause.

However the GC logs claims the application was not paused during this window.
Any help in understanding the root cause of this issue is appreciated.

Our target JVM: we had tried Java7 and Java8

```
java version "1.7.0_04"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_04-b20)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.0-b21, mixed mode)

java version "1.8.0_11"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_11-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.11-b03, mixed mode)
```

Our JVM options :

```
-Xms20G -Xmx20G -Xss10M -XX:PermSize=128M -XX:MaxPermSize=128M -XX:MarkStackSize=16M
-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+G1PrintRegionLivenessInfo -XX:+TraceGCTaskThread
-XX:+G1SummarizeConcMark -XX:+G1SummarizeRSetStats -XX:+G1TraceConcRefinement
-XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=100 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=65 
-XX:ParallelGCThreads=24 -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGC -XX:+PrintGCDetails 
-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintAdaptiveSizePolicy -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution 
-XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime -XX:+PrintGCApplicationConcurrentTime
-Xloggc:/common/logs/ocean-partition-gc.log
```